Markov Chain - Aperiodicity
Could someone help me with this question? Why do I need aperiodicity here? The way I showed it, I did not use aperiodicity. (The definition I know of aperiodicity is: A state $i$ is aperiodic if $p_{ii}^{(n)} > 0$ for some $N \geq 0$, for all $n \geq N$ (i.e., "$n$ large enough"))
Question: Let $(X_n){n=0,1,2,\dots}$ and $(Y_n){n=0,1,2,\dots}$ be two independent Markov chains on a common (denumerable) state space $I$, with respective initial distributions $\lambda^{(X)}$ and $\lambda^{(Y)}$ and transition matrices $P^{(X)}$ and $P^{(Y)}$. Let $W_n = (X_n, Y_n)_{n=0,1,2,\dots}$. Suppose that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are both irreducible and aperiodic. Show that $W_n$ is irreducible.
My answer: Choose any two states $(i, j)$ and $(k, l)$ in $I \times I$. We prove that $(i, j) \to (k, l)$ for $W_n$:
Because of irreducibility ${P}(X_n = k \mid X_0 = i) > 0 $ and ${P}(Y_n = l \mid Y_0 = j) > 0$. And because of independence: $P(W_n = (k, l) \mid W_0 = (i, j)) = P(X_n = k \mid X_0 = i) \cdot P(Y_n = l \mid Y_0 = j) (> 0). $

Irreducibility itself does not imply that ${P}(X_n = k \mid X_0 = i) > 0 $ and ${P}(Y_n = l \mid Y_0 = j) > 0$. E.g. the simple symmetric random walk $Z$ on the integers is irreducible, but ${P}(Z_n = 1 \mid Z_0 = 0) = 0 $ for any even $n$.

Right, so how did we use aperiodicity here then?

Since $X,Y$ are irreducible, it follows that for all states $i,j,k,l$ we have


$P(X_n=k{\;\mid\,}X_0=i) > 0$ for some $n$, say $n=n_1$.$\\[4pt]$
$P(Y_n=l{\;\mid\,}Y_0=j) > 0$ for some $n$, say $n=n_2$.


but it's not automatic that $n_1=n_2$.

Now suppose $X,Y$ are aperiodic.

Choose $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have 


$P(X_n=k{\;\mid\,}X_0=k) > 0$.$\\[4pt]$
$P(Y_n=l{\;\mid\,}Y_0=l) > 0$.


Now let $n=n_1+n_2+N$.

Then we have
$$
P(X_n=k{\;\mid\,}X_0=i)
=
P(X_{n_1}=k{\;\mid\,}X_0=i)
{\,\cdot\,}
P(X_n=k{\;\mid\,}X_{n_1}=k) > 0
$$
since
$P(X_{n_1}=k{\;\mid\,}X_0=i) > 0$
and
$P(X_n=k{\;\mid\,}X_{n_1}=k) > 0$.

Analogously we have
$$
P(Y_n=l{\;\mid\,}Y_0=j)
=
P(Y_{n_2}=l{\;\mid\,}Y_0=j)
{\,\cdot\,}
P(Y_n=k{\;\mid\,}Y_{n_2}=l) > 0
$$
since
$P(Y_{n_2}=l{\;\mid\,}Y_0=j) > 0$
and
$P(Y_n=l{\;\mid\,}Y_{n_2}=l) > 0$.

Then as in the last line of your proof attempt we get
$$
P\bigl((X_n,Y_n)=(k,l){\;\mid\,}(X_0,Y_0)=(i,j)\bigr)
=
P(X_n=k{\;\mid\,}X_0=i)
{\,\cdot\,}
P(Y_n=l{\;\mid\,}Y_0=j) > 0
$$
as was to be shown.

Consider, for example, both $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ to be simple symmetric random walk. Then  $(W_n)$, if started in state   $(0,0)$, will never reach state  $(1,0)$.
